как сделать каждому пользователю отдельную галерею на Wordpress?
Уточняю вопрос: мне нужно, чтобы каждый пользователь на сайте мог с фронтенда загружать свои фото, их просматривать и ими пользоваться. И не видеть фоток других пользователей! у себя в альбамах.
А по факту в Wordpress - одно хранилище медиа-файлов на всех, и все пользователи и все роли - видят все сразу.
"Пытаюсь сделать каждому пользователю отдельную галерею. Но в галерее все фото показываются сразу всем.
Как создать отдельную галерею каждому пользователю?
Может быть, как изменить права ролей пользователей? Стоит плагин Ultimate Member."

Галерея - это "комплект" картинок показываемых на фронте. Ты скорее всего  имеешь ввиду не это. Исправляй вопрос.

Вопрос уточнил, но если будет неясно - смогу еще раз... Сложность в том, что корректно сформулировать даже сложно, и гугл не находит ответов совсем!
